# How to reset JavaFX ComboBox value and re-show prompt text

Tags: java, javafx

Basically all I want is to have a button "clear" that when pressed clears the values of a few TextFields and a ComboBox and make them show their prompt text again. The TextFields work fine but the ComboBox only shows its prompt text the very first time and once I clear it doesn't show up again.

I have found a similar question there but the answer was to reset the selection and set the value to null, here is a minimal reproducible example of the controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML ComboBox<String> testBox;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        testBox.getItems().addAll("Item 1", "Item 2");
    }

    public void clear(ActionEvent event) {
        testBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        testBox.setValue(null);
    }
}
```

And the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="testBox" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="187.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="TEST" />
      <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="255.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clear" text="Clear" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Which didn't work (The prompt text doesn't show up again) and so I am here.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Does the combo box have focus? That may prevent it showing the prompt text.

Comment: @James_D Done. I hope this is what you needed me to do, take another look if you can.

Comment: Can you post the FXML and application class too, so I don't have to write them from scratch?

Comment: @James_D I added it, I also found the same question asked on reddit and the cause of the problem was that the author was using Java 11 and had the problem yet it worked fine for people using Java 8

Comment: @James_D This indeed isn't what I want, I need the user to be able to only pick certain values from the combobox, not enter their own. Is there any work-around to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#promptTextProperty) the combo box should not show the prompt text if it is not editable. So the fact that it shows the prompt text at the beginning appears to be a bug.

If you want to force it to show the prompt text when empty and not editable, you can do so with a custom button cell:

```
public void initialize() {
    testBox.setButtonCell(new ListCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(testBox.getPromptText());
            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
        }
    });
    testBox.getItems().addAll("Item 1", "Item 2");
}
```